# Accessing `http://localhost:8080/admin/djcelery/` returns 403 in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to access `http://localhost:8080/admin/djcelery/` in my Django admin. I can access `http://localhost:8080/admin` , I can run celery task but I can't access the djcelery admin site.

Here is my url

```
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Here is `settings.py`

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()


BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"

CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Do I have to add anything additional to access `admin/djcelery/` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already installed package

```
pip install django-celery
```

make sure you added it in **INSTALLED_APPS**

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ("djcelery", )
```

and run migrate

```
python manage.py migrate djcelery
```

if it still does not load you can glance 
[Detailed Documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend)

Comment: I have those setup, also note that I was able to run celery tasks, but just can't access the `admin/djcelery` page

Comment: Can you see Djcelery app section on main django admin page ? 
http://localhost:8080/admin
and if you have any extra information from log files

Comment: I can't see any app in my django admin page, despite having 3 apps, do I have to register to admin or something?

Comment: Can you provide an end to end example that have ` admin/djcelery` working

Comment: when you add 'djcelery' to INSTALLED_APPS, package is loaded and it's admin.py registers all djcelery apps to django admin

Comment: [Check This example it may help](https://github.com/simondlr/Django-Celery-Rabbitmq-full-example)